# python - In a FOR cicle, only use certain index that validates a condition

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, graph, conditional-statements

For a given square matrix(x,y) and a node, representing a graph (with 0 and 1 marking if there is an arrow pointing form x to y), i need to get the number of steps that i need to reach a certain node starting at any other node.
My problem is that when i am going to check the nodes from a distance greater than 1, i can only analyse the first direct node that connects to my given node always. I know that the error is in("if array[x][list(degree).index(n)]==1 and degree[x]==0:"). What should i do to iterate through all of the nodes?
(Code below)

!-btw, i can only use numpy, not networkx or other modules

```
def degree(node, matrix):
array=np.array(matrix)
degree=np.array([0]*len(array))
n=1
for u in range(len(degree)):
    if array[u][node]==1:
        degree[u]=1
    else:
        pass


while n<(len(degree)-2):
    for x in degree:
        if x==n:
            for x in range(len(array)):
                if array[x][list(degree).index(n)]==1 and degree[x]==0:
                    degree[x]=n+1
                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
    n+=1
    
for x,y in enumerate(degree):
    if y==0 and x!=0:
        degree[x]=-1
    else:
        pass  
degree[node]=0
return degree
```

Comment: Are you supposed to you Dijkstra, or maybe recursion?  Somehow, you have to remember where you've been so you don't visit there again.

Comment: You're only passing one node.  Don't you need a start and an end?

Comment: yes, it's some kind of djikstra but every arrow just weights one, it's for a social network analysis project

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple breadth-first search.  From the start node, we just try each of its neighbors, bumping up the cost every time we move forward.

```
def degree(target, matrix):
    results = [-1] * len(matrix)
    results[target] = 0
    visited = set([target])
    to_be_seen = [(target,0)]

    while to_be_seen:
        poss, cost = to_be_seen.pop(0)

        for i, n in enumerate(matrix[poss]):
            if n and i not in visited:
                results[i] = cost+1
                print( f"{target} to {i} is {cost+1} steps." )
                to_be_seen.append( (i,cost+1) )
                visited.add( i )
    return results

matrix = [
        [ 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 ],
        [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
]

print( degree( 0, matrix ) )
print( degree( 1, matrix ) )
print( degree( 2, matrix ) )
```

Output:

```
0 to 1 is 1 steps.
0 to 4 is 1 steps.
0 to 2 is 2 steps.
0 to 3 is 2 steps.
0 to 5 is 2 steps.
0 to 8 is 2 steps.
0 to 6 is 3 steps.
0 to 7 is 3 steps.
0 to 9 is 3 steps.
[0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3]
1 to 2 is 1 steps.
1 to 3 is 1 steps.
1 to 5 is 1 steps.
1 to 8 is 2 steps.
1 to 6 is 2 steps.
1 to 7 is 2 steps.
1 to 9 is 3 steps.
[-1, 0, 1, 1, -1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
2 to 3 is 1 steps.
2 to 8 is 1 steps.
2 to 6 is 2 steps.
2 to 9 is 2 steps.
[-1, -1, 0, 1, -1, -1, 2, -1, 1, 2]
```

Comment: sorry, but this isn't what i need to get, probably i did't explained very well, but it's for a social network analysis project, and it needs to evaluete every "degree of friendship" for a given "person", returning a list with n=paths needed to reach the original "person", zero for it'sel and -1 for the ones that dont have any degree

Comment: For each person N, you want to know how far every other person is?  That's a very minor change.  It just means printing everything found instead of returning the first one.